# Powershell: running JScript scripts without logo

Tags: powershell, jscript, file-association, wsh

I set `cscript.exe` as my default scripting host with the nologo option. Therefore in `cmd.exe`
I get, as expected:

```
> ftype jsfile                                                      
jsfile="C:\Windows\System32\CScript.exe" //nologo "%1" %*           

> reg query HKCR\jsfile\Shell\Open\Command                                                   

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jsfile\Shell\Open\Command                                                  
    (Default)    REG_EXPAND_SZ    "C:\Windows\System32\CScript.exe" //nologo "%1" %*     

> echo  WScript.Echo("Test Echo"); > test.js                        

> test.js                                                           
Test Echo
```

But, moving to Powershell:

```
> powershell -nologo                                                              
PS > .\test.js                 
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.8
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 

Test Echo
```

It seems that CScript does not get `//nologo` from Powershell shell. 
How can I fix this?

### More use cases

It also works with:

```
PS > cscript.exe //nologo test.js
Test Echo  
PS > cmd /c test.js 
Test Echo  
PS > cmd /c test
Test Echo
```

### Copy & Paste Test

Someone suggests it can be a bug. To check if it applies to you, you can copy the following in a PS console with elevated privileges:

```
## Change the host to cscript nologo and store old setting
$jstype="Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jsfile\Shell\Open\Command"        
$jsvalue=("`"$env:SystemRoot\System32\CScript.exe`"" + ' //nologo "%1" %*') 
$old=(gp  -Path $jstype   )."(default)"
Set-Item -Path $jstype -value $jsvalue                                  

## The output should be the same (i.e. nologo!)
echo  'WScript.Echo("Test Echo");' > test.js
cmd /c test
.\test.js

## Restore old settings
Set-Item -Path $jstype -value $old
```

Is `cmd /c test` and `.\test.js` output the same?

Comment: If you run  `PS> cmd /c test.js` it work or not ?

Comment: Mmmhh. Works for me.

Comment: @walidtoumi: yes; please see also question update.

Comment: @antonio: maybe is a bug...you can use a wrapper like this `function execute-js ($file) { cmd /c $file }` and execute it like this `execute-js -file file.js`

Comment: @walidtoumi: Can you please copy and paste the test I added to the question and tell me if the problem applies to you too?

Answer (score 0):

### Details on the problem

It seems that Powershell has a weird behaviour with respect to file associations.
If you paste the following snippet in an *elevated privilege PS shell*:

```
$jstype="Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jsfile\Shell\Open\Command"
Set-Item -Path $jstype -value "cscript.exe total non sense"
echo  'WScript.Echo("Test Echo");' > test.js
cmd /c test.js
```

... you get the deserved error for associating jsfiles with the command string `cscript.exe total non sense`.
But surprisingly writing:

```
.\test.js
```

works like a charm. So it seems that PS only reads the first item  of the open-command-string (here  `cscript.exe`) and then appends to it the user string (`.\test.js`),  totally disregarding the other elements of the open-string, here `total non sense`.

To confirm paste this:

```
Set-Item -Path $jstype -value "notepad.exe total non sense"
echo 'WScript.Echo("Test Echo");' > test.js
cmd /c test.js
```

`cmd.exe` opens the Notepad which proposes to create the file "total non sense.txt".

Now write:

```
.\test.js
```

Based on what I just said, the actual command run will be `notepad.exe .\test.js` and in fact  the Notepad will now open  `.\test.js`.

### Solution

Whether or not this is a bug, a possible solution is to create a batch script calling the `cscript.exe` with the desired parameters. I will name it `C:\Windows\System32\cscript.cmd`.

To create the script and the related association, paste:

```
echo "@cscript.exe //nologo %*" | out-file -encoding ASCII C:\Windows\System32\cscript.cmd
$jstype="Registry::HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jsfile\Shell\Open\Command"
$jsvalue=("`"$env:SystemRoot\System32\cscript.cmd`"" + ' "%1" %*') 
Set-Item -Path $jstype -value $jsvalue
```

As you see `//nologo` is moved from the registry to `cscript.cmd`.
Note that `echo "string" >` would produce a Unicode file, which `cmd.exe` dislikes, hence the ASCII filter. 
Print your new .js opening command:

```
cmd /c ftype jsfile
```

That is: `jsfile="C:\Windows\System32\cscript.cmd" "%1" %*`.

Now both:

```
cmd /c test
.\test
```

will produce:

```
Test Echo
```

without the banner, and note that in both cases  you don't need to specify the `.js` extension.

For simplicity I set `cscript.cmd` to run `cscript.exe` straight. You might want to specify its full path.